# Валидация форм ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, form

Скажите, как проверить заполненность полей mail и message в ajax форме ?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#send-mail").click(
        function(){
            sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form', 'config/contact.php');
            return false;
        }
    );
});

function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url,
        type:     "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#result_form').html('Успешно! Данные отправлены.');
        },
        error: function(response) {
            $('#result_form').html('Ошибка! Данные не отправлены.');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получать значение поля по ID и проверять не является ли оно пустой строкой. И так же сделать с [mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) используя регулярное выражение

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#send-mail").click(
            function(){
                if($("#id-input").val() !== ''){
                    sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form','config/contact.php');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        );
    });
```